# E-Commerce on App-engine: costs estimate

Tags: google-app-engine, e-commerce

With the idea of an online shop on GAE in mind. If coded right, with proper caching and concurrent requests, what should I expect for the costs in the "new" pricing model?

I didn't find any success stories involving e-commerce on GAE (should that be a hint?).
Technically there aren't any problems anymore, they now allow HTTPS on custom domains and I don't want to store credit card infos.

Let's say I got 500 visitors each day, distributed on about 10 hours. Say, that makes about 10k pageviews. How many frontend instances would that approximately need? 1, 2, 5, 10, 50, more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One instance can do 5-10 requests a second, if you enable [concurrent requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests). So you should be able to handle your load with one instance.

The other factor is datastore usage, which is highly app specific.

All-in-all we find AppEngine fairly priced. The biggest saving comes from the fact that you don't need admin and operations staff, which you would if you handled your own infrastructure and/or software stack.